# Ansible AWX: Unable to choose a playbook when tried creating AWX Job template

Tags: docker, github, centos8, ansible-awx

I'm tried creating a job template in AWX web interface.
the list of playbooks is not displayed on the interface although the project has been downloaded to git and is visible in the directory ~/var/lib/awx/projects.
my environment:

- centOS 8
- AWX 17.0.1
- Ansible 2.9.17
- docker-compose 1.28.2

[image]

Comment: awx sometimes does not pick up playbooks because of mismatch in names. try to see if creating a new playbook with different names help.

Answer (score 0):

The yml file must not be empty and must have right syntax.
After that , always sync project and then check

Answer (score 0):

I had this same challenge when creating a new Job Template on **Ansible AWX** setup on **Ubuntu 20.04**.

I created some playbooks in a repository that was added to a project. I then created a Job Template and selected the Project, but none of the playbooks were added to the project.

My playbook looked this way:

```
- name: Check if SSHD is running
  command: systemctl status ssh
  ignore_errors: yes
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

I simply added `hosts` to the playbook and it showed up on the Job template for me to select. So my playbook was modified to look this way:

```
- name: Check if SSHD is running
  hosts: all
  command: systemctl status ssh
  ignore_errors: yes
```

**Note**: The value for `hosts` could be something else. For me, it was `all`.

**Resources**: [Playbooks aren’t showing up in the “Job Template” drop-down](https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/1636#issuecomment-441901684)

That's all.

**I hope that helps**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Once I made sure my git repo was up-to-date, I manually typed in the playbook name in the awx template creation screen, and my playbook was selected.